# Google Analytics: different results with and without a dimension specified

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm facing a pretty weird behavior of Google Analytics API.

Below are the examples of the queries I'm making using the Query Explorer. Dates and all other options are absolutely identical in both queries.

**First query**

```
metrics=ga:pageviews
filters=gaPagePath==/my_article_uri/
```

Result: **975**

**Second query**

```
metrics=ga:pageviews
dimensions=ga:country
filters=gaPagePath==/my_article_uri/
```

Result: Azerbaijan: 3, Netherlands: 60, Russia: 2067, Singapore: 22, United States: 157

Total: **2309**!

Question: Why the results are not equal?

I tried to google this, and it seems that the problem is the scope of the metrics/dimensions, but still can't really understand.

**EDIT**

For the first query, the results are NOT sampled.

However, for the second query (with the dimension specified) there IS sampling:

```
"containsSampledData": true,
"sampleSize": "499365",
"sampleSpace": "1568579"
```

Might be the reason?

Comment: are the results sampled at all?

Comment: For the first query: "containsSampledData": false. For the second one (with a dimension specified) however the results are sampled: "containsSampledData": true,
"sampleSize": "499365",
"sampleSpace": "1568579".

Comment: Updated the question with the sampling info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sampling reported back in the query, I believe the inaccuracies are due to sampling. The second query is based on about 32% of sessions.

If you decrease your date range so that both are not sampled, then they should match.

Comment: Yeah, sampling seems to be the problem! Changed the date range to just yesterday, and the results became equal. Thanks!